# Unable to post simple string data to Web API from AngularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, web-services, http-post, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to get a json string from my angular app to a Web API. I have looked all over the internet the past 6 hours trying and failing miserably to figure out what I am doing wrong.

I have checked the network console and I can see the json as form data, but my WEB api for some reason is NOT getting it. I have looked at several other posts but none seem to help with my particular issue. Any direction would be great. I already tried using the "transform" fix, but that didn't help.

ENTRY POINTS TO WEB API

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/SkeltaInterfaceController/SaveWorkflow")]
public bool SaveWorkflow([FromBody] string json)
{
    ...
}
```

ANGULAR CALL

```
$scope.SaveWorkFlow = function () {
    $http({
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        method: "POST",
        url: webAPI,
        data: {'DATA' : 'TEST DATA'
        }
    })
}
```

**EDIT: I** changed the angular call to this

```
$scope.SaveWorkFlow = function () {
    $http({
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        method: "POST",
        url: webAPI,
        data: {'DATA' : 'TEST DATA'}
    })
}
```

The Web API looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/SkeltaInterfaceController/SaveWorkflow")]
public bool SaveWorkflow([FromBody] TestModel json)
{
    ...
}
```

And the model

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string DATA { get; set; }
}
```

I am still getting a null value for DATA though, something I setup wrong?

Comment: Can you import `Request.InputStream`? Also if you could please provide the full .NET class.

Comment: What backend framework do you use? What is the version of Angular?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your issue comes down to the WebApi controller method expecting to receive a string, but you are passing it an object. Is it at least hitting the method but receiving null?

It depends what you are trying to send to the WebApi controller method, but if you mean to send an object, you should create a model that represents that object in your WebApi project and have the method take an object as the parameter.

For example, the way you have it right now you would do something like:

```
public class SaveModel 
{
    public string DATA {get; set;}
}


[HttpPost]
[Route("api/SkeltaInterfaceController/SaveWorkflow")]
public bool SaveWorkflow([FromBody] SaveModel model)
{ ...
```

Comment: To answer your question, yes. It is hitting the method but receiving a null.

Comment: That sounds like the problem I described. Since you are passing an object w/ a single string parameter "DATA" in the $http request, the WebApi method receives and deserializes that object. However, since it was expecting just a string and received some entirely different object, it thinks the request is invalid and gives you null for that parameter. If all you are trying to pass to the WebApi method is a string, you should be able to pass that as the data rather than a JSON object w/ a string parameter.

Comment: Check my edit. I either did something wrong, or there is a deeper issue.

Comment: Can you try changing the content-type to "application/json"?

Comment: I was just about to comment on that. I changed the type to application/json and it works flawlessly. I didn't WANT to create a model, but if that's what I have to do then that's ok. Kudos for pointing me in the right direction. EVERY example I found kept telling me to use the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", so that should help you understand why it ws even there.

Comment: Like I said earlier, if all you want to send is a string, you should be able to set the parameter type back to string and just send a string rather than an object, like { ...., data: 'TEST DATA', ....}, rather than { ...., data: { 'DATA': 'TEST DATA' }, .... }.

Comment: Sending in a string would be easier, but it's better to just make the model on the back-end. It puts my json object into the object for me without me having to mess with json parsers manually. IT's a good fix. :)

Answer (score 39):

Though you have got an solution, there are some ways to **`POST`** simple **`string`** data (not an object) **to a `Web API`** service.

Let's say you have a POST API like this (in Test ApiController)

```
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    //do something with value
}
```

From `AngularJS` you can post to this method like

**(1)** data as `JSON` (default)

```
$scope.Test = function () {
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/api/Test",
        data: JSON.stringify("test")
    });
};
```

This will use `Content-Type: application/json` by default. And server will treat the data as JSON. If you look at the request, you'll see the request body is a simple string, like

```
"test"
```

For complex objects, you'd see them JSON formatted.

**(2)** data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (as in your example)

```
$scope.Test = function () {
    $http({
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        method: "POST",
        url: "/api/Test",
        data: $.param({ "": "test" }),
    });
};
```

Here, we are explicitly specifying the content type to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so we have to send data in that format (much like url query string). And, here, the *empty key* in data is *just to satisfy `Web API`'s strange model binding requirement!* The resulting data will be encoded like

```
=test
```

which we'have done with `$.param({ "": "test" })`. One reason for this, `FromBody` is used mainly to send `object`, not simple primitive values.

So, the basic **problem** with your code was, you had specified *Content Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded* and you were sending the data as *JSON!*

Comment: FYI: The $.param never worked for me. I tried that one. I don't know what the issue was.

Comment: @Willy The `$.param({ "": "YourStringValue" })` works just fine, as long as (1) the key is empty, (2) Content-Type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. If it didn't work check the request that is going to the server AND/OR the dev console for other errors.